# Passing cookies in webview android

Tags: android, webview

I have build an application to load `WebView` with passing `cookies`.my application works fine in KitKat version of android.
but `WebView` is not loading in `jelly bean` or **lower versions**. that means my `WebView` is not passing `cookies` in `jelly bean` or **lower versions**.

Is this possible not to load `WebView` in lower **android versions**? If possible, then how to do it?

please guide me and help me.

Hear i store cookie in my activity.

```
   CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();


            CookieSyncManager syncManager = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(MainActivity2.this);
            syncManager.sync();
            CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
            manager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
            CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);

            CookieStore cookieJar = manager.getCookieStore();
            cookies1 = cookieJar.getCookies();
            editor.putString("coockies", String.valueOf(cookies1));


            //List<Cookie> cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
            for (int i = 0; i < cookies1.size(); i++) {
                 cookie = cookies1.get(i);
                Log.d("cookie", String.valueOf(cookie));
            }
```

and hear i pass cookie in webview

```
enter code here wv = new WebView(this);
    wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);


    HttpCookie sessionCookie = myactivity.cookie;
    Log.d("Session Coockies",String.valueOf(sessionCookie));

    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();


    if (sessionCookie != null) {

        cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
        String cookieString = sessionCookie.getName() + "=" + sessionCookie.getValue() + "; domain=" + sessionCookie.getDomain();
        Log.d("cookistring",cookieString);
        cookieManager.setCookie("", cookieString);
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();

       // String cookieString = sessionCookie.getName() + "=" + sessionCookie.getValue() + ";domain=";

    }

    wv.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    wv.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    //setContentView(myWebView);
    String url="my url";
    Log.d("url",url);
    wv.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: please post code where you are passing cookies..

Comment: maybe this link will help http://code.walletapp.net/post/46414301269/passing-cookie-to-webview , here dev has introduced some delay after removing session cookie..